# Error: Class '\App\User' not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola estaba haciendo un proyecto y luego decidimos hacerle un nuevo controlador y modelos, soy nuevo en laravel y no entiendo a la perfección el flujo, yo en mis `routes` ya apunto a mi controlador nuevo y uso las mismas vistas pero no se que pueda estar fallando este es mi código:

```
login.blade.php


@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container" class="wrap">
    <div class="container" id="conte" >
        <!-- Formulario -->
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }} 

            <!-- Ahora creado este metodo nos dira que le metodo login no existe y ahora lo creamos en en controlador -->
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> -->
            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <input name="name" 
                       placeholder="USUARIO" 
                       id="input-form"
                       value="{{ old('name') }}"> 
                {!! $errors->first('name', '<span class="help-block mensajerror">:message</span>') !!}
            </div>


            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="password" 
                       name="password" 
                       placeholder="PASSWORD" 
                       id="input-form1" 
                       style="color:gray; background: #dee2e6; margin-top: -7px;">
                {!! $errors->first('password', '<span class="help-block mensajerror">:message</span>') !!}
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #007bff00; border-color: #007bff00; position: absolute;"></button>
        </form>

        <!-- Imagen -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="./img/logo.png" id="img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Recuperar Contraseña -->
        <div class="container" id="forgot">
            <a href="" id="text-forgot">RECUPERA TU CONTRASEÑA</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Mi archivo de rutas **web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'AdminController@showLoginForm'); // Podemos dejarle el middleware aca ->middleware('guest') o en el controlador

//Obtenemos la pagina dashboard, lacreamos con el controlador DashboardController , llamamos el metodo index y le damos el nombre dashboard
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::post('login', 'AdminController@login')->name('login'); 
//post es el metodo usado, enviamos la url login y el controlador Admincontroller en el metodo @login  y el nombre de la ruta sera login tambien

//esto hara que al acceder nos dira que expiro por inactividad esto quiere decir que no le hemos enviamos el csrf (desde el formulario)


Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function __contruct() {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => 'showLoginForm']); // Para que solo los no autenticados vean esta pagina
    }

    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('auth.login'); //Retornamos la vista login ubicada en la carpeta auth
    }


    public function login() {

        $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [

            //Reglas de validacion
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string'

        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {    // Auth::attempt($credentials ,Devuelve un boolean . No olvidar importar auth(use auth)
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        // Cargamos los input para que recuerde el valor al momento de retornar a la pagina por error de datos withErrors (nombre) mensaje
        // En caso de no pasar autentificacion devuelve error 
        //cargamos el mensaje de error de resources/lang/en/auth .llave en este caso failed
        return back()->withErrors([$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')]) 
                     ->withInput(request([$this->username()]));


    }

    public function logout() {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

// Como queremos es loguearnos con el name solo debemos cambiar el email por name pero como hay varias referencias a email creamos un metodo que nos devuelva el campo con el queremos autenticar
    public function username() {
        return 'name';
    }



    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Admin  $admin
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Admin $admin)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Admin  $admin
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Admin $admin)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Admin  $admin
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Admin $admin)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Admin  $admin
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Admin $admin)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

metodo index del dashboard

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // Para que solo deje pasar a los usuarios autenticados
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

     public function index() {
        return view('dashboard');
     }
}

?>
```

Detalle del error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\pikum.mapu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php
>
> ```
>          * @param  array  $credentials
>          * @return bool
>          */
>         public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
>         {
>             $plain = $credentials['password'];
>
>             return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Create a new instance of the model.
>          *
>          * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
>          */
>         public function createModel()
>         {
>             $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->model, '\\');
>
>             return new $class;
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Gets the hasher implementation.
>          *
>          * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher
>          */
>         public function getHasher()
>         {
>             return $this->hasher;
>         }
> ```

Este es el modelo(Admin.php) que deberia usar pero no estoy seguro de que deberia llevar:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Parte de la estructura de la carpeta por si acaso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error me da luego de que me `logueo` cuando me debería mostrar mi vista dashboard

[AQUI EL PROYECTO](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Iewo6Za2j6QE-FaVFROW4Rr9n15vkrSp)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tiene su clase `User` ? en `App` ? ¿No se eliminó?

Comment: En la carpeta `config` del proyecto, hay un archivo `auth.php` , busque el array `providers` está por defecto el modelo del `guard` que se usa para la autenticación y middleware , reemplace el `App\User::class` por su modelo `App\Admin::class` , y me cuenta como va.

Comment: listo, si era eso amigo muchas gracias me podrias explicar el porqué ? bueno eso y le cambie en admincontroller.php la funcion que me devuelve el nombre del campo a usuario ya que en mi tabla se llama usuario y no name  pero ahora solo tengo que ver por que no me ingresa a mi tabla cuando le pongo el usuario correcto y ni siquiera me dice el motivo y se supone que deberia :/ por cierto lo subi al google drive por si le quieres echar una ojeada :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es común cuando se desea autenticar o validar controles de acceso con `middleware` , por defecto se usa el modelo `User` , esto está especificado en el archivo `config/auth.php` en la sección `providers` , en la propiedad `model` se define el modelo a usar en ese caso por defecto `App\User::class`. Si desea cambiar a otro modelo debería modificar ahí y colocar el que desea en este caso `App\Admin::class`.

Esto solucionará el error pero lo que intenta hacer es crear `login` con diferentes modelos para lo cuál debe hacer algunas modificaciones. Para este caso sería mejor crear un nuevo `guard`  en el archivo `auth.php` en la sección `guards` tendría y en la sección  `providers`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    // Nuevo Guard
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    //Nuevo Provider
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

Y su Controlador sería de otra manera, usando los traits que proporciona `laravel` , `AuthenticatesUsers` , su controlador podría quedar de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    //trait
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    //La vista de login
    protected $loginView ="auth.login";

    // El nombre del guard que se creo para administradores
    protected $guard ="admins"


    // Este método funcionará para hacer la redirección después de login
    protected function authenticated()
    {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

}
```

Además su modelo como parte importante debe extender de `Authenticatable`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    //
}
```